# how implement feedback page which send mail through gmail account in android application

Tags: java, android, smtp, gmail, user-feedback

hello everyone I want to make feedback page and that page there are four `EditText` 
1. name 
2. email 
3. phone 
4. feedback body 
so I want to get user feedback by email. 
I think its possible with SMTP and Gmail.

please help me.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

```
 Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "Your Email Here ...");
  email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
  email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
  email.setType("message/rfc822");
  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
```

Refer this [how-to-send-email-in-android](http://www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-send-email-in-android/)